# Почему trigger('click') не срабатывает на смартфонах, но отлично работает на ПК?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно что бы при клике на какой то блок, сработал trigger('click') на другой класс. Почему этот код не работает в мобильных браузерах? https://jsfiddle.net/ow7mc9pd/

```
$('.social').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

У смартфонов нет понятие "click", в данном случае лучше плагин использовать для jquery - jTap.

Просто напиши

```
<script src="jquery.tap.min.js"></script>
```

(естественно после самого jquery)
и потом сможешь использовать к примеру это (для нажатия)

```
$('selector').tap(handler);
```

[Полное руководство](https://habr.com/post/191078/)